# spring application context not finding configuration bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a configuration class:

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfig {
    @Value(value = "${com.test.myValue")
    private String myValue;
    
    public String getMyValue() {
        return myValue;
    }
}
```

And a non-bean class that use it:

```
public class MyPOJO {
    private static MyConfig config = SpringContext.getBean(MyConfig.class);
    
    public String getMyValue() {
        return config.getMyValue();
    }
}
```

And this is the SpringContext class that I use to get the bean:

```
import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class SpringContext implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private static ApplicationContext context;

    /**
     * Returns the Spring managed bean instance of the given class type if it exists. Returns null
     * otherwise.
     * 
     * @param beanClass
     * @return
     */
    public static <T extends Object> T getBean (Class<T> beanClass) {
        return context.getBean(beanClass);
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext (ApplicationContext context) throws BeansException {
        SpringContext.context = context;
    }
}
```

but when I run this code:

```
MyPOJO pojo = new MyPOJO();
String value = pojo.getMyValue();
```

it fails on NullPointerException on return `config.getMyValue();` which means config is null and wasn't created.

what could be the issue?

note that I don't believe it's an issue with component scan since i have an annotation that scan the entire package.

Comment: why not make this `MyPOJO` as spring bean with `@Component` annotation ?

Answer (score 0):

You have mistakes in the `MyConfig` class:

1. There is no closing curly bracket `}`
2. Two different types for the `myValue`.

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfig {
    @Value(value = "${com.test.myValue}")
    private Integer myValue;

    public Integer getMyValue() {
        return myValue;
    }
}
```

Also, it's important to know the context when you create the POJO.
You should ensure that POJO creation is fulfilled before the Spring context is ready.

Comment: ignore any minor syntax error, i hand written it to explain the issue, fixed now.
also not sure what you mean when you say "You should ensure that POJO creation is fulfilled before the Spring context is ready.", how do I do that?

Comment: @Gilad Baruchian where do you call `new Pojo()`? Describe the context. If you did it just in `main()` before `SpringApplication.run` execution it won't work because the Spring context isn't initialized yet.